# Cypress and Browserstack Internal Server Error Zip Upload Failed

Tags: automation, cypress, browserstack

I am trying to run my Cypress tests locally using Browserstack and keep getting the following error.  I have tried to add more npm dependencies, tried adding the `--local-identifier` when launching the `./BrowserStackLocal` yet I keep getting this error. From what I have seen here https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress this should all work fine even with the "Setup Local Testing" that I followed yet it does not.

```
[4/14/2021, 8:52:51 AM] - info: Reading access key from the environment variable BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY
[4/14/2021, 8:52:51 AM] - info: Validating the config
[4/14/2021, 8:52:51 AM] - info: Creating tests.zip with files in .
[4/14/2021, 8:53:40 AM] - info: Uploading the tests to BrowserStack
[4/14/2021, 8:56:07 AM] - error: Internal Server Error!
[4/14/2021, 8:56:07 AM] - error: Zip Upload failed.
[4/14/2021, 8:56:07 AM] - info: Deleted tests.zip successfully.
```

I have the following run settings in the browerstack.json

```
        "cypress_config_file": "cypress.json",
        "project_name": "Test",
        "build_name": "Build no. 1",
        "exclude": [],
        "parallels": "5",
        "npm_dependencies": {
          "@types/node":"^14.0.22",
          "browserstack-cypress-cli": "^1.8.1",
          "cypress": "7.0.1",
          "cypress-commands": "^1.1.0",
          "cypress-localstorage-commands": "^1.4.1",
          "cypress-react-selector": "^2.2.1",
          "start-server-and-test": "^1.11.5",
          "typescript": "^3.9.6",
          "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.6.0",
          "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.6.0",
          "eslint": "6.8.0",
          "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.1.0",
          "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
          "eslint-plugin-chai-friendly": "^0.6.0",
          "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.2",
          "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
          "eslint-plugin-jest": "^23.13.2",
          "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
          "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
          "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.3",
          "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "2.5.1"
        },
        "package_config_options": {},
        "headless": true
    },
    "connection_settings": {
        "local": true,
        "local_identifier": "CypressLocalConnection1",
        "local_mode": null,
        "local_config_file": null
    },
    "disable_usage_reporting": false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We faced a similar issue previously and later encountered that there is a restriction of the file size of 200 MB for tests.zip that gets created. Try to use their exclude feature: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress/exclude-files to remove the unwanted files and folders to be uploaded to reduce the file size.

Comment: My file size is 101mb sadly.

Comment: so interestingly enough, browerstack just updated their error message and it says that `The directory size which contains the cypress config file is more than 200 MB. For more info, check out https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress/exclude-files` but when I try exclude it never works. My zip is only 99mb and I put `"exclude": ["node_modules/*", "/SYSTM/release/*", "capacitor/*", "cordova/*", ".git/*"],` but they are always included. Any thoughts? Thanks so much.

Comment: Looks like the regex which you have written is a bit wrong. 
"exclude": ["node_modules/**", "/SYSTM/release/**", "capacitor/**", "cordova/**", ".git/**"]. 
Modify all your single * regex to double ** as * will only exclude files in that directory and not the sub directories